# XAML User Control Base Element Type

Tags: xaml, inheritance, user-controls

In XAML, you can create your own reusable control type as a UserControl object like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
            <Button Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But you can also just change the base type in that view to be the same type as the content container like this:

```
<Grid x:Class="MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button Content="Test"/>
</Grid>
```

What is the difference between these two options? In my example, they both derive from `FrameworkElement` and diverge in inheritance from there. But it seems like they function the same.

I'm sure there's a good reason for one versus the other, but I'm having trouble coming up with a good scenario to justify the distinction. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, the main reason for having different base types is properties.

If you find that a UserControl doesn't have the dependency properties you need - perhaps you'd like it to expand some content from time to time, then you could base it on an Expander rather than going into the code-behind to type 'propdp' and reinvent the wheel, replace the template instead of just stuffing things into the "content" property and bind to the Expander's "IsExpanded" property.

Doing this allows you to blur the line between UserControl and Custom Control by essentially making a copy of the template of an existing control and adding to it; taking advantage of existing properties and adding new ones in code behind if needed.

The UserControl tag itself is just an average base, but if you feel something else is more fitting to what you want the control to be, then use that.

Or, if all you want is a glorified container to lob a bunch of textboxes or something in that will be frequently used, then you needn't change a thing.